# How can I get last day in the month Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, unix

I am trying to get the last day in this current month, or the last month, what I am using to workaround this "problem" is checking with:

```
if [ $DAY -eq 1 ]; then
    code here;
fi
```

If the day is 1, so it's saying that I am in the new month, so I need to domy backup as well.

Do you guys have any idea how can I do the check if today is the last day in the Month "January 31th" for example???

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use GNU date:

```
if [[ $(date -d "+1 day" +%m) != $(date +%m) ]]
then
    echo "Today is the last day of the month"
else
    echo "Today is NOT the last day of the month"
fi
```

Answer (score 13):

Getting the *last* day for a month is sometimes tricky, because not all months have the same days number of course.

One way to do it is to get this month's first day, add a month to that (to get next month's first day) and then subtract a day.

```
date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-01) +1 month -1 day"
thu jan 31 00:00:00 -07 2019
```

And remember that `date` can output whatever format you want (argument starting with `+`).

```
date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-01) +1 month -1 day" '+%F'
2019-01-31
```

See `man date` for more info or `info '(coreutils) date invocation'` for even more.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: the clear calculation logic! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This gives you last day of previous month

```
date -d "-$(date +%d) days -0 month"
```

and this gives you last day of current month

```
date -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month"
```

---

```
if [[ $(date  +%d%m%Y -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month") != $(date +%d%m%Y) || $(date  +%d%m%Y -d "-$(date +%d) days -0 month") != $(date +%d%m%Y)  ]]
    echo "Today is NOT the last day of the month"
else
    echo "Today is the last day of the month"
fi
```

Comment: If you are on the 30th (last day of last month), "+1 month" does not bump you to the 31st of this month.